# what browsers do not support native forEach, filter, every and so on

Tags: javascript, browser, underscore.js

After reading documentation of [`underscore.js`](http://underscorejs.org) I found (to my surprise) that actually not all browsers support

- [`forEach`](http://underscorejs.org/#each)
- [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter)
- [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every)
- [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some)

methods. Previously I thought that these methods are implemented everywhere. Checking what browsers does not support them, did not give me any information: `my chrome, IE9, firefox 13` all supports them.

So where can I find what browsers support them and may be what other methods are not supported everywhere?

P.S I am sorry, I think I confused someone with my question. I know that all browsers support underscore's foreach. In the question I refer to native methods.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the current status of Javascript ES5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042020/whats-the-current-status-of-javascript-es5)

Comment: Sure, the question are not the same (because you only asked for a part of ES5), but I wanted to link it for others

Answer (score 12, accepted):

here is a nice compatibility table: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 3):

I normally take a look at http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/ which has a pretty good table off support for allot of javascript methods.

Answer (score 0):

All browsers will support underscore's methods [`forEach`](http://underscorejs.org/#each), [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter), [`every`](http://underscorejs.org/#every) and [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) (and any other methods). It is just that some of them will be not as efficient because they don't have native counterparts.

As an example, check `forEach`: underscore first checks if the `Array` prototype supports `forEach` natively with `nativeForEach = ArrayProto.forEach`. If it does, it uses the native prototype method. If not, it uses it's own implementation with a `for` loop (in collection functions, see `var each = _.each = _.forEach = function(obj, iterator, context) ...`.

Answer (score 0):

They ave been around for some time. JavaScriptKit is a good resource.

All modern browsers with JavaScript 1.6+ support implement these methods.

[Javascriptkit: Arrays](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/arrays.shtml)